# Handle AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate Url correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin, avplayer, avasset

I'm trying to use AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate with AVPlayer(streaming). First I found out that none of the AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate methods were called if the url scheme was http or https. Fair enough. I added a custom scheme like "custom_scheme://". The following method is called:

```
public override bool ShouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource (AVAssetResourceLoader resourceLoader, AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest loadingRequest)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

The problem is...I actually need to use http or https, otherwise, how can this url work? Should I change the url on the method above? If so..how can I make another request?

I need to get to ShouldWaitForResponseToAuthenticationChallenge method to pass in a certificate and respond to the challenge.

Answer (score 0):

You can map your custom scheme URL to http or https (or both) in `shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource` and make another http/https request from there.

I'm not sure how further authentication plays out after that. I'd have thought it was part of the secondary request you make.

Comment: I can handle further authentication if ShouldWaitForResponseToAuthenticationChallenge is ever called. But I don't know what kind of another request you're talking about. Do you know how to do this?